# Is it possible to replace glutInit(&argc, argv)?

Tags: opengl, glut

I am trying to convert example (.exe) from Rob Farber ([link](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/222600097)) to DLL so it can be called from LABView.

In example is called `glutInit(&argc, argv)`.

Is it possible to replace `glutInit(&argc, argv)` with something what can be placed in DLL?

Or can be values of `argc` and `argv` set manualy?

Comment: Are you passing any arguments into it, or none at all?

Comment: I have declared `int argc` and `char **argv` and do nothing else with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argc is the number of arguments passed to you executable, argv contains the actual arguments. First value is simply integer, second value is `char**`. So if you do not need to pass any glut-specific program arguments to your application pass argc = 0, argv should be a `char**` and it does not matter what are it's contents. If you need to pass glut specific arguments to your glutInit, simply create a `char**` that contains them(place arguments from index 1 not from 0) and set argc to number of arguments you are passing.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to convert example (.exe) from Rob Farber (link) to DLL so it can be called from LABView

If you want to execute something in LabVIEW's context, then GLUT is an absolute NoGo! LabVIEW does its very own event loop and management. GLUT's MainLoop would severely conflict with LabVIEW's internals.

I've written my fair share of LabVIEW modules, and to be frank, off my head I've no idea, how I'd create a proper OpenGL context to integrate into one of LabVIEW's windows, not even to speak about instruments.

Thinking about it, I'd probably spawn a independently running thread, with its own windows and event processing and establish some sort of communication channel between the LabVIEW side and the local side. Also I'd make sure to allocate everything on the independent thread's side from thread local storage (TLS), because I've found LabVIEW's own memory management of beeing not very keen to cooperate with other libraries' memory allocations. (One of my standard patterns you'll find in my interfacing VIs is, that I pass over memory in form of LabVIEW arrays over to my modules, to work on that, and my modules won't allocate anything on their own.)

Comment: thanks for your reply and time. the example combine CUDA and OpenGL. OpenGL/GLUT creates its own window. I am not trying to display image in LABView window. I managed to set LABView to call all DLLs from one thread (it is requirement from CUDA). I even managed to run successfully these DLLs from LABView. Problem is when I stop LABView program and try to run it again whole LABView crash. I thought that parameters in `glutInit(&argc, argv)` cause problem but I am not sure anymore.

Comment: @user1281071: This sounds like one of those memory allocation issues I mentioned. You don't have to use GLUT BTW. From your problem description I think using a PBuffer would do the trick. And you could make the DLL a per process singleton (it's ages since I did that the last time, so I couldn't tell you how to do it exactly right now) so create the context only one time, and then only reuse if the VIs get restarted. \*sigh\* …I hate LabVIEW.